# How to sum up char code of word in T-SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I need to sum char codes of last 6 symbols of string.
I can sum there last 6 characters through C# like this:

```
string str = "helloWorld";
var sumLastSixCharacters = str.Where((ch, i) => (i > 3) ).Sum(x => x); //631
```

And I've written the following code to sum up last 6 characters, but, in my view,
there should be more elegant solution:

```
DECLARE @Foo VARCHAR(10);
SET @Foo='helloWorld';

SELECT   
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, @Foo) IS NULL   
    THEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 5,1)) + ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 6,1)) + 
        ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 7,1)) + ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 8,1)) + 
        ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 9,1)) + ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Foo, 10,1)) 
    ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
END AS Result;
```

Guys, does anybody know how can I calculate sum of last 6 characters in better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a *recursive CTE* against the reversed string

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='helloWorld';

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT REVERSE(@str) AS OriginalReversed
          ,1 AS Position
          ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str),1,1) AS CharAtPos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.OriginalReversed
          ,r.Position +1
          ,SUBSTRING(r.OriginalReversed,r.Position+1,1)
    FROM recCTE AS r
    WHERE Position<6 --specify the character count here
)
/*
--Use this to see the intermediate result
SELECT * 
FROM recCTE
*/
SELECT SUM(ASCII(CharAtPos)) --631
FROM recCTE;
```

### Some explanation

The CTE will take the reversed input, start a `1` and take the first character (from the end).

Then it iterates down, increasing the position by one to read the next character.

This way you will transform `test` to

```
t
s
e
t
```

Using `SUM` against the `ASCII` values is your needed result

### UPDATE

Summing up the ASCII-values might be a bad idea... any word with the same characters will lead to the same result...

If you just need to get a number out of a string you might use this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)='helloWorld';
SELECT CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@str,6) AS BINARY(6)) AS BIGINT)
```

This will just take the binary chunk of 6 bytes and interpret this as `BIGINT`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, is it possible to put this code into scalar function?

Comment: @StepUp Besides the fact, that most scalar functions are bad performers... Yes it is... Just wrap it accordingly, should be easy...

Comment: I had a problem with ``BIGINT`` generating Ids greater than ``2,147,483,648``. Converting to ``INT`` is not an option as it generated too many conflicts for short words (1A, 1B, 1C). Instead, I used ``ABS(CHECKSUM(@str)) % 1000000`` to give me a big enough range of unique numbers.

Answer (score 2):

this does it.  I modified it to solve the original ask.

For me, I needed a function to evaluate concatenated fields to find duplication of patterns like:
abc | cba
and
cba | abc

I can now find these instances and replace one with the other so now I'd just have
abc | cba

call it with SELECT database_of_your_choice.dbo.CREATE_STRING_CHECKSUM('yourstringhere')

--code below

```sql
use database_of_your_choice
go

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CREATE_STRING_CHECKSUM
(
    @string nvarchar(100) = NULL
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @pos int = 0,
            @len int = len(@string),
            @ascii_sum int = 0,
            @iter_count int = 6

    --just in case you pass a string with less than 6 characters
    if(@iter_count > @len) set @iter_count=@len

    --loops for @iter_count: 6 times
    while @iter_count > 0 begin
        --passing @len to SUBSTRING will look at the right-most char decremented
        --with each iteration: get the right most 6 characters
        set @ascii_sum += ASCII(substring(@string,@len,1))
        set @len -= 1
        set @iter_count -= 1
    end 

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ascii_sum

END
GO
```